# Firestore - Fetch a user based on a skill

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have stumbled upon a problem using firestore, it may be my limited knowledge about it. Not sure. However what I want to do is to query my collection using a query parameter, that holds a string that is a skill and return the user(s) that has this skill. I have on purpose added all users inside an array instead of creating seperate docs for each user since I think it should be more efficient (correct me if I am wrong please).

Here's what I have tried codewise:

```
  const result = await db
    .collection('foo')
    .where(`skills.${q}`, '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      if (snap.empty) {
        console.log('its empty');
      } else {
        const docs = snap.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(docs);
      }
  });
```

`q` in the code is for instance `bar` or `baz` in the `skills` object.

And here's an image of the representation in the database: 
[image]

And for a clearer view of the structure I screenshoted postman where I posted the data as well:
[image]

Hope it was clear enough and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users field is actually a list type field with two elements.  You can tell because of the "0" and "1".  Each of these list items contains a map with more fields.

**It's not possible to query individual properties of list elements of documents in Firestore.**  If you want to find documents with a certain set of skills, you should instead have a top-level list type field called "skills" that contains the strings of the skills you want to search.  Then you can do an [array-contains-any query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) like this:

```
  const result = await db
    .collection('foo')
    .where('skills', 'array-contains-any', ['bar', 'baz'])
```

Comment: I think the `users` array is causing problems, still getting an empty response back. When trying this: `const result = await db
    .collection('foo')
    .where('skills', 'array-contains-any', ['bar', 'baz'])
    .get()
    .then(snap => {
      if (snap.empty) {
        console.log('its empty');
      } else {
        const docs = snap.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(docs);
      }
    });`

Comment: Please read my answer again - it's not possible to perform the query you want with the data you have now.  You will need to restructure the data.

Comment: I realized that after I actually posted the comment, sorry and thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I did what you said and re-structured the data. Storing every new user in a new document, makes it easier that way. Thanks for help again :)

Comment: Just to pile on and support @DougStevenson 's answer - I have a similar issue, and solve it as he does.  Some of the confusion comes from using an SQL mindset in Firestore's NoSQL world - SQL *really* wants DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) - data in one-and-only-one place.  NoSQL encourages you to repeat *static* data wherever it helps, to keep queries fast and efficient.
You can see the philosophy in the pricing structure - reads and writes are far more expensive than storage.  Larger documents rarely hurt your costs.